# Cann't delete childs rows in manytomany Associations

Tags: mysql, playframework, ebean

I have a ManyToMany Association that does not allow me to delete a parent when the child item are linked to other entities...
Anybody has the solution please ?

**Parent Model :**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012 Steve Chaloner
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package models;

import be.objectify.deadbolt.java.models.Permission;
import be.objectify.deadbolt.java.models.Role;
import be.objectify.deadbolt.java.models.Subject;
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import java.util.List;

import models.utils.AppException;
import models.utils.Hash;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.annotation.PrivateOwned;
import com.avaje.ebean.Query;
import play.db.ebean.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author Steve Chaloner (steve@objectify.be)
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "authorised_user")
public class AuthorisedUser extends Model implements Subject
{
    @Id
    public Long id;

    //@Constraints.Required
    //@Formats.NonEmpty
    //@Column(unique = true)
    public String userName;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    public String email;

    public String fullname;

    public String profession;

    public String language;  

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public String password_hash;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date createdt;

    public String createby;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date moddt;

    public String modby;

    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public Boolean validated = false;

    public String imagepath;

    @ManyToOne
    public Site site;            

    @PrivateOwned
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<User_Sites> relationSitesList = new ArrayList<>();   

    @PrivateOwned
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Image> relationImagesList = new ArrayList<>(); 

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<SecurityRole> roles;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<UserPermission> permissions;

    public static final Finder<Long, AuthorisedUser> find = new Finder<>(Long.class,
                                                                         AuthorisedUser.class);

    @Override
    public List<? extends Role> getRoles()
    {
        return roles;
    }

    @Override
    public List<? extends Permission> getPermissions()
    {
        return permissions;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentifier()
    {
        return userName;
    }

    public static AuthorisedUser findByUserName(String userName)
    {
        return find.where()
                   .eq("userName",
                       userName)
                   .findUnique();
    }


    public static AuthorisedUser findByEmail(String email) {
        return find.where().eq("email", email).findUnique();
    }


    public static AuthorisedUser findByFullname(String fullname) {
        return find.where().eq("fullname", fullname).findUnique();
    }


    public static AuthorisedUser authenticate(String email, String clearPassword) throws AppException {

        // get the user with email only to keep the salt password
        AuthorisedUser user = find.where().eq("email", email).findUnique();
        if (user != null) {
            // get the hash password from the salt + clear password
            if (Hash.checkPassword(clearPassword, user.password_hash)) {
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    public void changePassword(String password) throws AppException {
        this.password_hash = Hash.createPassword(password);
        this.save();
    }


    public static boolean confirm(AuthorisedUser user) throws AppException {
        if (user == null) {
            return false;
        }

        user.validated = true;
        user.save();
        return true;
    }

    public static PagedList<AuthorisedUser> page()                           

    {    


        RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(" SELECT "  

                                            +"user.id, "
                                            +"user.user_name, "                                            
                                            +"user.email, "
                                            +"user.fullname, "
                                            +"user.profession, "     
                                            +"user.password_hash, "                                      
                                            +"user.createdt, "                                      
                                            +"user.createby, "                                            
                                            +"user.moddt, "
                                            +"user.modby, "                                            
                                            +"user.validated "

                                            +"from authorised_user as user "
                                            +" ")


                  .columnMapping("user.id", "id")
                  .columnMapping("user.user_name", "userName")                  
                  .columnMapping("user.email", "email")
                  .columnMapping("user.fullname", "fullname")
                  .columnMapping("user.profession", "profession")                                    
                  .columnMapping("user.password_hash", "password_hash")
                  .columnMapping("user.createdt", "createdt")
                  .columnMapping("user.createby", "createby")                  
                  .columnMapping("user.moddt", "moddt")
                  .columnMapping("user.modby", "modby")                                    
                  .columnMapping("user.validated", "validated")                                                                    

                  .create();

                  Query<AuthorisedUser> query = Ebean.find(AuthorisedUser.class);
                  query.setRawSql(rawSql);



                  PagedList<AuthorisedUser> result = query.findPagedList(0, 0);
                  return result;


    }                        
}
```

**Child Model**

```
package models;
import be.objectify.deadbolt.java.models.Role;
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import models.utils.AppException;
import models.utils.Hash;
import play.data.format.Formats;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;
import com.avaje.ebean.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.annotation.PrivateOwned;
import com.avaje.ebean.Query;
import play.db.ebean.*;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * @author Steve Chaloner (steve@objectify.be)
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "security_role")
public class SecurityRole extends Model implements Role
{
    @Id
    public Long id;
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    public String name;
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date createdt;
    public String createby;
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date moddt;
    public String modby;
    public static final Finder<Long, SecurityRole> find = new Finder<>(Long.class,
                                                                       SecurityRole.class);
    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public static SecurityRole findByName(String name)
    {
        return find.where()
                   .eq("name",
                       name)
                   .findUnique();
    }
    public static SecurityRole findById(Long id) {
        return find.where().eq("id", id).findUnique();
    }

}**
```

**Here is the SQL creation :**

```
create table authorised_user (
  id                            bigint auto_increment not null,
  user_name                     varchar(255),
  email                         varchar(255),
  fullname                      varchar(255),
  profession                    varchar(255),
  language                      varchar(255),
  password_hash                 varchar(255),
  createdt                      datetime(6),
  createby                      varchar(255),
  moddt                         datetime(6),
  modby                         varchar(255),
  validated                     tinyint(1) default 0,
  imagepath                     varchar(255),
  site_id                       bigint,
  constraint uq_authorised_user_email unique (email),
  constraint pk_authorised_user primary key (id)
);

create table security_role (
  id                            bigint auto_increment not null,
  name                          varchar(255),
  createdt                      datetime(6),
  createby                      varchar(255),
  moddt                         datetime(6),
  modby                         varchar(255),
  constraint uq_security_role_name unique (name),
  constraint pk_security_role primary key (id)
);

create table authorised_user_security_role (
  authorised_user_id            bigint not null,
  security_role_id              bigint not null,
  constraint pk_authorised_user_security_role primary key (authorised_user_id,security_role_id)
);

alter table authorised_user add constraint fk_authorised_user_site_id foreign key (site_id) references site (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_authorised_user_site_id on authorised_user (site_id);

alter table authorised_user_security_role add constraint fk_authorised_user_security_role_authorised_user foreign key (authorised_user_id) references authorised_user (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_authorised_user_security_role_authorised_user on authorised_user_security_role (authorised_user_id);

alter table authorised_user_security_role add constraint fk_authorised_user_security_role_security_role foreign key (security_role_id) references security_role (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_authorised_user_security_role_security_role on authorised_user_security_role (security_role_id);
```

Those models are taken from deadbolt security & roles.

If someone has a suggestion of answers do not hesitate please.

Comment: This is more a business issue than a technical one. You need to answer the question : what happens to the children if I delete the parent ? Should I delete them in cascade, link them to another parent, leave them as orphans ? Currently, it prevents you from deleting because of `on delete restrict`.

Comment: Hi, if I remove on delete restrict ? >>>the children will be deleted ?

Comment: Depends on the default setting. Check here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html. You might need to use `CASCADE`. Be careful, you need to be sure that it is what you want to do. You might lose unexpected data if you don't think about it before applying CASCADE.

Comment: I already use cascade,
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<SecurityRole> roles;
but this is not working when deleting role from security_role (parent)...

Comment: You need to be sure, the cascade is also set in MySQL. Sometimes the ORM does not apply correctly constraints when generating the database schema.

Comment: c4k : can you add your last comment as an Answer please? you were right, by changing (on delete restrict) to (on delete cascade) it works fine :) & this is what i've do :

**alter table authorised_user_security_role add constraint fk_authorised_user_security_role_security_role foreign key (security_role_id) references security_role (id) on delete cascade on update restrict;create index ix_authorised_user_security_role_security_role on authorised_user_security_role (security_role_id);**

Answer (score 0):

Check [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.ht%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bml) for `on delete`.

Be careful, you need to be sure that it is what you want to do. You might lose unexpected data if you don't think about it before applying `cascade`.

So changing `on delete restrict` to `on delete cascade` in you SQL script will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you c4k, you were right, I changed my SQL to this and it works pretty fine, thank you really really and so much:
(however, i can't ++your_answer_as_useful because i am newer ...sorry)

```
alter table authorised_user_security_role add constraint fk_authorised_user_security_role_security_role foreign key (security_role_id) references security_role (id) on delete cascade on update restrict;

create index ix_authorised_user_security_role_security_role on authorised_user_security_role (security_role_id);
```